# Utilisation de l'adjectif "numéral"

Tags: adjectifs

Par exemple pour parler de la proximité de deux arrondissements parisiens (les 3e et 4e), peut-on parler de proximité à la fois *numérale* et géographique ?

J'ai un doute sur *numérale* et je ne crois pas que *numérique* soit approprié dans ce cas, car il fait plutôt référence à une quantité.

What do you think?

Comment: Bien qu'un peu tirée par les cheveux, je trouve cette formule appropriée, à titre personnel. Elle semble bien correspondre à la définition de l'adjectif "numéral" : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9ral
Je n'en fais pas une réponse car quelqu'un saura mieux développer que moi ici.

Comment: Lroximité séquentielle

Answer (score 4):

Même si le sens peut faire hésiter, j'éviterais ***proximité [numérale](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9rale)*** qui risque de provoquer pas mal de perplexité.

On parle bien de *proximité alphabétique* donc ***proximité [numérique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9rique)*** serait mieux compris, et a le mérite d'exister, même s'il est beaucoup plus rare (<200 fois) que *proximité géographique*.

[image]

*Numérique* se spécialise cependant de plus en plus pour désigner ce qui à trait aux équipements connectés à Internet.

@Personne me souffle ***proximité séquentielle***, ce qui se défend puisque les arrondissements sont nommés en séquence et en spirale. Dans le même esprit, on pourrait aussi tenter ***proximité ordinale***.

Tu peux aussi abandonner l'idée d'un adjectif et parler simplement de ***proximité des numéros***...

En tout cas, ce n'est pas *proximité « numéricale »* comme ce pourrait l'être en anglais.

@Greg ajoute *proximité « [numérotationnelle](https://forum.hardware.fr/hfr/Discussions/TV-Radio/direct8-2005-2012-sujet_42505_957.htm#t5702632)* », un quasi-hapax...

Comment: Dans la liste des arrondissements de Paris dessinés en spirale, la *proximité séquentielle* implique la *proximité géographique*, cette dernière est aussi partagée avec le ou les autres arrondissements partageant les mêmes rayons.

Comment: @Personne Je prends ;-)

Comment: On pourrait dire *proximité par la numérotation* (ou alors, pour rire, *proximité numérotationnelle* ? Personne l'a encore inventée, celle-là)...

Comment: J'aime bien "ordinale", merci

Answer (score 0):

La proximité de deux arrondissements (parisien ou autre) sur le plan de la différence entre leurs numéros d'identification et en même temps sur le plan de la distance physique qui les sépare nous amène à un concept mathématique de distance généralisée qui n'a pas d'utilité et pas d'incidence dans la vie de tous les jours aussi bien que dans les problèmes comme ceux de la logistique. C'est donc quelque chose d'inconnu et sans une explication préliminaire et/ou une définition,  un terme tel que proximité numéro-géographique (ou même « à la fois numérale et géographique ») ne peut pas évoquer quoi que ce soit de bien défini chez le lecteur. Moi-même, ayant à lire une telle expression et étant forcément enclin à penser à des nombres plus importants que les numéros d'identification qui existent en rapport avec un arrondissement (ceux de sa population, de sa superficie,…) je n'ai aucune raison de penser que les nombres dont il est question sont  les numéros d'identification ; de plus, je n'ai aucune idée sur la façon dont est exprimée cette proximité qui résulte de deux proximités combinées. Il faut donc d'abord définir cette proximité (définition de distance pour pouvoir comparer et donc évaluer la proximité), qui autrement ne correspond à rien (ce ne peut pas être un terme issu du processus de combinaison par [compositionnalité](https://fr.qwe.wiki/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality)). En observant d'abord  ces préliminaires  on peut ensuite utiliser un terme défini tel que « proximité numérale et géographique ». Cependant, pour la raison déjà mentionnée que la référence à des nombres dans ce terme est tout à fait  générale, on n'aura pas un terme bien spécifique, qui en plus sera long. Donc, pour quelque chose d'aussi compliqué et technique que cette distance, tout indique qu'un terme plus utile sera un sigle ou mot court la nommant uniquement et exigeant le savoir préliminaire qui s'y rapporte ; il est clair que le terme long envisagé ne communique pas de véritable information et ne pourra jamais le faire; il est donc plutôt inutile littérairement parlant et aussi mathématiquement parlant (et c'est plutôt un concept mathématique). Un terme tel que « proximité NI-G » semble être une meilleure solution ; bien sûr, les possibilités sont nombreuses (nige, nigé, nigéo, …).

Je crois que dans le présent cas d'utilisation d'un adjectif en référence aux nombres le choix entre les deux adjectifs considérés est bonnet blanc et blanc bonnet.

[numéral](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9ral) […] qui est relatif à des données représentées par des chiffres
[numérique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9rique) […] qui se présente sous la forme de nombres ou de chiffres,

Cependant, on n'écrit pas « identification numérale » alors qu'« [identification numérique](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=19&year_end=2008&content=identification+num%C3%A9rale%2Cidentification+num%C3%A9rique&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidentification%20num%C3%A9rique%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cidentification%20num%C3%A9rique%3B%2Cc0) » est courant ; comme les numéros des arrondissement servent à les identifier, il faudrait choisir cette dernière combinaison (si l'une des deux doit servir).

Comment: merci pour cette réponse nourrie.